# Add sources header thing

Tags: feature-request

I just saw this over at [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/61412/17672) (part of the question is included to show the exact location of the header):

[image]

Text of header above the answer, for the visually impaired and in case of image removal:

> Want to improve this post? Add citations from reputable sources by editing the post. Posts with unsourced content may be edited or deleted.

I think being able to add this is a neat feature, can we have something like this?

Comment: This is amazing hope moderators will use it in the future

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a so-called [post notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186087/295232), and it's available on all sites in the network. The 'problem' is, only ♦ moderators can add it:

[image]

I'm a moderator on three other sites in the network and regularly apply answer notices when I see a low quality answer (often after it has been flagged as Very Low Quality) of which I think it *might* be able to be edited into a proper answer. I guess you could use a custom moderator flag asking to apply a post notice, but I haven't seen anybody do that so far and I'm not sure what the moderators here think about this.

Comment: I have not ever looked into this option, so thanks for this answer! A lot of posts we close need more than just citations to be improved (or are troll questions), but this looks like it could be helpful.