# Generic Response to Questions Without Evidence of Prior Search Effort

Tags: discussion, site-activity, site-policy

If the user asks question that shows no evidence of prior search/research effort you might use the following generic response (special thanks to Mark C. Wallace - mod from History.SE for allowing us to repurpose their generic answer).

> Welcome to Economics:SE. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, `[we expect questions to provide evidence of prior research](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).` That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our `[help center](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help),` and `[other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question)` provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

---

Note to future mods: You can also consider using automatic [post notice](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2044/15517) in appropriate situations.

Comment: May I suggest combining all such generic responses into one single meta post? This is easier to search-copy-paste the relevant snippets. [Meta.tex.sx](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/430/18228) has a similar system which I find pretty useful.

Comment: Also, making the responses into `code` (instead of quotes) would help preserve hyperlinks when copying.

Comment: @HerrK. I edited the relevant parts into code, I will also create one single meta post with all community responses in one meta post later this week