# All Generic Responses

Tags: discussion

Per request from community all generic responses to questions and answers were also put in this one thread (with links to original posts) so users can find all generic community responses in one thread.

---

### Quick Links

**Generic response(s) to...**

- [homework questions](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2089/)
- [unsourced answers](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2118/)
- [questions without prior search effort](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2119/)

Answer (score 4):

[**Generic response to Homework Questions**](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1771/generic-response-to-homework-questions)

If you see any, just post this as a comment, usually the user will edit their question.

> Hi, Welcome to Economics SE! we have a policy regarding homework questions where we require that you show some work before an answer is provided. More on this topic here:`https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/economics-se-policy-on-homework-questions`

the user in question shows his work using only images an appropriate response is:

> Hi, Welcome to Economics SE! we have a policy regarding homework questions where users must demonstrate effort using text, markdown syntax and/or images space provided in the text of his question submission for the site. Using only images as proof of work is insufficient. for more details see:`https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/economics-se-policy-on-homework-questions`

Answer (score 3):

[**Generic Response to Questions Without Evidence of Prior Search Effort**](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2083/generic-response-to-questions-without-evidence-of-prior-search-effort)

If the user asks question that shows no evidence of prior search/research effort you might use the following generic response (special thanks to Mark C. Wallace - mod from History.SE for allowing us to repurpose their generic answer).

> Welcome to Economics:SE. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, [we expect questions to provide evidence of prior research](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help center](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help), and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

`Welcome to Economics:SE. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, [we expect questions to provide evidence of prior research](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help center](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help), and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.`

Answer (score 3):

**Using abbreviation without first defining them.**

`Hi. Welcome to Econ Stack Exchange. Try not to use abbreviations unless you first define them. This helps with discoverability with search engines, not to mention the average reader.`

Answer (score 2):

[**Generic Response to Unsourced Answers**](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2084/generic-response-to-unsourced-answers)

This generic response should be used for answers that talk about statistics, research or results that are not common knowledge in economics (i.e. something that a person with undergraduate degree in economics should know) and which are not self-contained (e.g. it should not apply to self-contained answers presenting a model), and which lack any references to credible sources supporting the answer (or otherwise violate the [FAQ on community standards for answers](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2113/faq-on-community-standard-for-answers)).

> Hi, welcome to Economics:Stack Exchange. Please consider improving the answer by adding references from reputable and scholarly sources. As many other science stacks do, we require formal proofs, statistical evidence or links to external sources for answers making claims which are not common knowledge. Unsourced material can be edited or deleted. For more details see our [help center](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and [FAQ on community standards for answers](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2113/faq-on-community-standard-for-answers)

`Hi, welcome to Economics:Stack Exchange. Please consider improving the answer by adding references from reputable and scholarly sources. As many other science stacks do, we require formal proofs, statistical evidence or links to external sources for answers making claims which are not common knowledge. Unsourced material can be edited or deleted. For more details see our [help center](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and [FAQ on community standards for answers](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2113/faq-on-community-standard-for-answers)`

Answer (score 2):

[**Welcome, plus help with LaTeX**](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1272/59)

This comment is useful when a new user asks a question that includes mathematics that isn't properly formatting into LaTeX.

> Welcome to economics.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq) to familiarize yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.

`Welcome to economics.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarize yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.`