# Generic Response to Unsourced Answers

Tags: discussion, site-activity

This generic response should be used for answers that talk about statistics, research or results that are not common knowledge in economics (i.e. something that a person with undergraduate degree in economics should know) and which are not self-contained (e.g. it should not apply to self-contained answers presenting a model), and which lack any references to credible sources supporting the answer (or otherwise violate the FAQ on community standards for answers).

> Hi, welcome to Economics:Stack Exchange. Please consider improving the answer by adding references from reputable and scholarly sources. As many other science stacks do, we require formal proofs, statistical evidence or links to external sources for answers making claims which are not common knowledge. Unsourced material can be edited or deleted. For more details see our `[help center](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)` and `[FAQ on community standards for answers](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2113/faq-on-community-standard-for-answers)`

---

Note to future mods: You can also consider using automatic [post notice](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2044/15517).