# Editing other people's incorrect answers to make their incorrect point more obvious

Tags: discussion

Obviously one should not vandalize answers or make them worse, but what if an answer is incorrect and somewhat long or complicated?

A specific answer made some claims that are incorrect if we apply the usual definitions of the concepts used. I asked for clarifications in the comments, describing a classic Econ 101 situation and asking the writer of the answer to apply their definitions, which they did. IMO the resulting claim would be marked as incorrect in most Econ 101 exams.

Can I edit their incorrect claim into their answer (near to the top even) to make it more clear to passersby that the definitions are not used correctly? (I am the only downvoter, and there is also an upvoter.)

I am hesitant about this because I would be editing in an incorrect point to someone's answer, which feels weird, even though it is in line with the intent of their answer.

Comment: Ethically it sounds wrong, but I understand the desire.

Comment: @EconJohn Can you explain why you think it is ethically wrong? I don't think the edit would conflict with the author's intent.

Comment: I have no rationale. Just a bad feeling about it. I encourage others to weigh in on this point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably just let the wrong (and also unclear answer) get voted as such or ignored and try to make a better answer that is clearer and also correct. If you do want to edit an incorrect answer, go ahead and just make a note in the edit notes on the nature of the correction. It can be reverted by the original person posting the answer.

Answer (score 4):

A useful approach in some cases is to make the edit but also add a comment on the lines of: "I've taken the liberty of editing your answer to clarify its meaning.  Please feel free to reverse my edit if it does not reflect your intended meaning."

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to do that under SE rules. In fact SE rules actually de jure encourage it. There are certain guidelines that should be followed thought (see below).

At the same time, despite this being de jure allowed, de facto many members of SE community do not like the idea (e.g. see this [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64841/editing-someone-elses-wrong-answer-to-make-it-right)).

However, note we still have the [community standards](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2113/faq-on-community-standard-for-answers) for an answer. If an answer makes some non-common knowledge claims without a reference you can flag it, they get note on their post and if they dont fix the issue the answer gets deleted in 3 days.

---

Rules on editing as laid out in the [help center](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/editing):

> **Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?**

> All contributions are licensed under Creative Commons, and this site is collaboratively edited, like Wikipedia. If you see something that needs improvement, edit it!

> Editing is important for keeping posts clear, relevant, and up-to-date. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.

> **When should I edit posts?**

> Any time you see a post that needs improvement and are inclined to suggest an edit, you are welcome to do so.

> Some common reasons to edit a post are:

> To fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
> To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)
> To include additional information only found in comments, so that all of the >information relevant to the post is contained in one place
> To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages
> To add related resources or hyperlinks
> Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged; try to make the post significantly better when >you edit, correcting all problems that you observe.

> **What happens when I edit a post?**

> The post will be updated to show the latest editor, as well as the original author. All edits are saved and tracked in a public revision history with attribution to each editor.

> A post's revision history can be viewed by clicking the date and time at the bottom of the edited post (e.g., "edited 3 days ago").

> Editing a question or answer also bumps the question to the top of the homepage.

> **Who makes sure that proposed edits are good?**

> Any user can propose edits, but not all edits are publicly visible immediately. If a user has less than 1,000 reputation, the suggested edit is placed in a review queue. Two accept or reject votes are required to remove the suggested edit from the queue and either apply the edit to the post or discard it.

> Users with more than 1,000 reputation are considered trusted community members, and can edit posts without going through the review process. The original author of a question or answer may always edit their own post, regardless of reputation level.

> **What happens if someone suggests a bad edit?**

> If a user without edit privileges proposes an edit that does not comply with the guidelines above, it is ordinarily rejected in the review process. Even if a bad edit is applied to a post, other users will generally fix it. Users with sufficient reputation may elect to roll back the post to a previous version (by viewing the revision history of the post and selecting the version they would like to display).

> Additionally, any user who submits many rejected edits will be banned from suggesting further edits for 7 days.

**What is a rollback?**

> A rollback reverts a post to a previous version in the edit history. The rollback action itself then appears as the most recent item in the edit history.

Comment: "*de facto many members of SE community do not like the idea*" Perhaps I did not express myself well enough. I do not intend to correct the answer, I intend to make it clearer, and since IMO it is incorrect, it will stay incorrect. The meta post you link to is about "righting" wrong answers.